# How do I minimise this?

Tags: calculus

I have $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}$. I have to minimise $f$ subject to $y^n - x^n = 1 - k$, where $k$ and $n$ is are constants.

Comment: Are you familiar with Lagrange’s multipliers?

Comment: Not yet. Is that the only way?

Comment: That’s the usual, straightforward way. But yoy could proceed with substitutions and elementary inequalities.

Comment: I've ended up in $x^n=k$ and $y^n=1$.

Comment: Hi Michael, what method did you use?

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then $f$ is unbounded below, since setting $x = -\sqrt[n]{1-k}$ makes $y = 0$. The question becomes more interesting when $n$ is even.